# How can I use jquery .when to access json data to append to a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am creating that function that looks for urls in a data attribute on a page and then finds the data-url object, gets the url for that page and accesses the json from that page and appends it into a dynamic slider.

The data urls look like follows when rendered:

```
<ul id="data-urls" style="display: none;">

    <li data-number="1" data-title="life-is-light" data-url="/pages/life-is-light"></li>

    <li data-number="2" data-title="our-biodynamics" data-url="/pages/our-biodynamics"></li>

    <li data-number="3" data-title="winemaking" data-url="/pages/winemaking"></li>

    <li data-number="4" data-title="our-land" data-url="/pages/our-land"></li>

    <li data-number="5" data-title="the-people" data-url="/pages/the-people"></li>

</ul>
```

I created a function that used a `$.each` loop to start it off but I ran into issues where the appended items from the `$.get` were being added in a random order and not according to the list above which is always in order. This is what I created and what caused the issue:

```
$.each( $("#data-urls li") , function () {

  var dataUrl = $(this).attr('data-url');
  var dataTitleObj = $(this).attr('data-title');

  $.get( dataUrl, function( data ) {
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  var body = data[i].body_html,title = data[i].title,id = data[i].handle,orderNum = data[i].id;
  $('.page-holder').append('<section data-order="" id="'+ id +'" href="#'+ id +'" class="big-stretch active"><figure class="inner"><div class="inner-stretch"><div class="box"><h1 class="">'+ title +'</h1><hr class="style-line"><p class="">'+ body +'</p></div></div></figure></section>');
  timber.largeImageResize();
});



  console.log(data);

  }, 'json').done(function() {

var h1 = $('#life-is-light .inner .inner-stretch h1');
var text = h1.text().split(' ');

for( var i = 1, len = text.length; i < len; i=i+2 ) {
    text[i] = '<span class="italic">' + text[i] + '</span>';
}
h1.html(text.join(' '));

  });

});
```

This appends the items correct but they appear in wrong order on page refresh sometimes, which is not consistent. So I then came up with using $.when but what I am struggling with is on the above function I can grab each urls data as json with this `}, 'json').done(function() {` with `$.when` there is no easy way to do this, when I do `console.log(data);` after the above function I get this:

```
Object {page: Object}
page: Object 
author: "Kat Wiggins"
body_html: "Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
created_at: "2014-11-05T10:51:14-05:00"
handle: "our-biodynamics"
id: 22933611
published_at: "2014-11-05T10:50:00-05:00"
title: "Our Biodynamics"
updated_at: "2014-11-05T10:53:11-05:00"
```

The new function I want to use is $.when:

```
$.when.apply(null, $.map($("#data-urls li"), function(elm) { return $.get($(elm).data('url')); }) ).then(function(responses) {
    $.each(responses, function(data) {
    });
});
```

How can I get exactly the same with the above function as I did with my original one without it trying to reorder the html on page refresh and also successfully get the data correctly?

Comment: So what is the problem? Your code should work fine.

Comment: What does the json look like, I'm guessing `data` in `$.get` is an object, and `i` is really a key, not an index for an array, and objects have no order, so to solve it, you should use an array instead.

Comment: I cannot correctly output any json data, the structure needs to output json. I can console.log(responses); but it only gives me the first url of that chain of urls

Comment: adeneo, how could that be done with what I have created already?

Comment: You have to change the JSON to an array, not an object, as arrays will be kept in order when parsed, objects neccessarely won't, as they don't have any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is almost fine. The only problem is that when you pass multiple promises to [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) then corresponding responses will be available not in form of the array, but as individual arguments. That's why in your code `responses` indeed refers to the first response.

Try to iterate over them this way:

```
var promises = $("#data-urls li").map(function() { 
    return $.get($(this).data('url')); 
});

$.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
    var responses = [].slice.call(arguments);
    $.each(responses, function(i, data) {
        console.log(data[0]); // json response
    });
});
```

Comment: This works fine but how can I get the json so I can access objects within each array item?

Comment: Yes, depending on your JSON structure. Check console. For example http://plnkr.co/edit/gtLvdTxOrSZGMdRArFZa?p=preview

Comment: okay just tried data[0].title and nothing came out the json structure is as follows: `Object {page: Object} page: Object author: "name" body_html: "" created_at: "2014-11-05T10:50:35-05:00"handle: "life-is-light"id: 22933567published_at: "2014-11-05T10:49:00-05:00"title: "Life is Light" updated_at: "2014-11-06T08:05:53-05:00"`

Comment: Check `console.log(data[0].page.title)`?